# How to restore my Mac OS X using time machine onto a new hard drive install?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have a mid 2010 MacBook Pro and want to install a new hard drive but I'm not sure how to restore my Time Machine back ups (Yosemite) with a new hard drive.